# How to remove characters from the beginning of txt file using bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I have some txt file look like this:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

I wanna add to my script some command to remove:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,
```

and get this effect:

```
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
```

I try with some sed commands but don't work and i don't have more ideas.

Comment: add your `sed` commands which did not worked please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to skip the backslash. Try again with:

```
sed 's/data:image\/jpeg;base64,//' file > newFile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with the text input which contains `/` then you can use different separator like `#` or `@` etc inside `sed`.

```
sed 's#data:image/jpeg;base64,##' file
```

or this for inplace replacement in the file.

```
sed  -i 's#data:image/jpeg;base64,##' file
```